# Computing math expression in python

Tags: python, math

I want to solve easy expressions by replacing numbers with variables. For example:
`ab^2 = r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*cos(180-t3)`
I can solve this equation with a simple code like this
`r1 = 3 r2 = 4 t3 = 90 ab = math.sqrt(r1**2+r2**2-(2*r1*r2*math.cos(math.radians(180-t3))))`
However I want to see if there is any easier way to calculate the answer to this expression since I have about 20 equations that use these variables to get an answer

I have tried sympy and other libraries however I only want to calculate the answer not solving an equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sympy import symbols, cos, rad, sqrt, N

# Define symbols
r1, r2, t3 = 3, 4, 90
ab, r1, r2, t3 = symbols('ab r1 r2 t3')

# Equation
eq = sqrt(r1**2 + r2**2 - 2*r1*r2*cos(rad(180-t3)))

# Substitution
result = eq.subs({r1:3, r2:4, t3:90})

# Numeric Evaluation
result = N(result)

print(result)
```